# pointer to function points the jmp instruction in c

Tags: c, function-pointers, disassembly

I viewed the disassembly of my c code, and found out that pointer to function actually point the `jmp` instruction, and doesn't point the real start of the function in memory (doesn't point `push ebp` instruction, that represents start of function's frame).

I have the followed function (that does basically nothing, it's just an example):

```
int func2(int a, int b)
{
    return 1;
}
```

I tried to print the address of the function- `printf("%p", &func2);`

I looked at the disassembly of my code, and found out that the address that is printed is the address of the `jmp` instuction in assembly code. I would like to get the address that represents the start of function's frame. Is there any way to calculate it from the given address of the `jmp` instruction? 
Moreover, I have the bytes that represents the `jmp` instruction.

```
011A11EF E9 CC 08 00 00       jmp         func2 (011A1AC0h)
```

How can I get the address that represents the start of function's frame in memory (`011A1AC0h` in that case), only from the address of the `jmp` instruction and from the bytes that represents the `jmp` instruction itself? I read some information about that, and I found out that it is relative `jmp`, which means that I need to add the value that `jmp` holds to the address of the `jmp` instruction itself. Not sure if that's a good direction for the solution, and if it is, how can I get the value that `jmp` holds?

Comment: And what happens when the fiunction gets back to the end and has to return so the caller can clear the stack?  It has nowhere to go back to...

Comment: It is quite unusual to "need" the actual address of a function in C, other than the one that is provided by the language itself. Are you sure you are not having an X-Y problem here?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah It will pop the return address off the stack of course.

Comment: Not sure that I have x-y problem. The problem is that i need a way to find that address. It's something I must have(that address), unfortunately it's not really negotiable. I would like to get some offers to deal with it :)

Comment: You have asked a question that involves specific hardware and software but have not said a word about what hardware and software you are using.

Comment: Your use of "function's frame" is incorrect. Frame refers to the **stack** reserved by that function, *not* the memory address of the **code**.

Comment: Define this MSVC Debug Linker 'Function Order' option /ORDER:@"your_filename.cpp" 
It allows direct calls from function-to-function i.e., prevents the linker generating function-to-JMP-to-function.

Answer (score 2):

E9<sub>16</sub> is the Intel 64 and IA-32 opcode for a jmp instruction with a *rel32* offset. The next four bytes contain the offset. Your disassembler shows them as “CC 08 00 00”, but this is reversed; the offset is 000008CC<sub>16</sub>, which is 2252<sub>10</sub>. The offset is a signed 32-bit value that is added to the EIP register to obtain the address of the jump target. The EIP contains the address of the next instruction to be executed.

So, in this specific case, take the address of the byte just beyond the jump instruction and add the 32-bit offset.

However:

- I count 11 forms of jmp instruction in Intel 64 and IA-32 manual. Who knows what the compiler may use when you make a slight change to source or compiler switches and recompile? You would need to be prepared to decode any form of the jmp instruction, or perhaps other instructions the compiler might use.
- Intel has some legacy segment features in its architecture. The code segment on your system might be one big thing so you do not have to worry about that, but I cannot provide assurance.
- Your compiler might have used this jmp instruction as a convenient way to create a value for the pointer rather than using the routine’s entry point (the proper term for the instruction where function execution normally begins, not frame) because it makes the linker do the relocation work instead of requiring the compiler to insert instructions to do that work at run-time (specifically, at the time the function address must be evaluated so it can be assigned to the pointer). This is somewhat of a guess, but the compiler might do something else next time. You are treading significantly outside normal computing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to get your question, but take [this sample](https://godbolt.org/g/TmjRD4):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int x)
{
  return x+1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  printf("foo = %p\n", foo);
  return 0;
}
```

Which produces the following disassembly:

```
foo(int):
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        addl    $1, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "foo = %p\n"
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
        movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
        movl    foo(int), %esi  # pass the label argument (2) to printf
        movl    $.LC0, %edi     # pass the format argument (1) to printf
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    printf
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
```

As you can see, only the label is passed to printf. This label is resolved as an address by the compiler.

Also notice that it will be hard for you to get an absolute address of a running binary: the [ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) will choose a random base address for the binary. The offsets inside the binary still holds, hence relative calls.

Answer (score 0):

On X86 machines E9 is the opcode for JMP rel16/32. So the cpu is going to use the value 0x000008CC as jump offset. The base address is the address of the instruction following the JMP instruction.

Comment: The width of the displacement does not indicate the main architecture width. Intel’s 64-bit architecture supports jmp instructions with 8-bit and 32-bit relative displacements.